# Policy gradient: why does this converge with Adam and not SGD?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, optimization

I am looking into policy gradient methods. I stumbled into this implementation:
https://gist.github.com/calclavia/cfcd41ad4e47d7b9b6ab8af15410747a
It uses a Nesterov Adam optimizer.

If I run it, it converges and gets good scores on [OpenAI Gym's CartPole-v0](https://gym.openai.com/envs/CartPole-v0/).

However, if I change the optimizer from Adam to stochastic gradient descent (SGD), it never converges and seems to act randomly. Why is this? Is there something about policy gradient methods which make SGD a poor choice?

NOTE: there is a bug in that code which only runs the episode for 100 time steps. The episode can run for up to 200 time steps. I fixed this when running it.

Comment: What happens if you remove your 100 time step limit fix? I ask because you have to be careful with that, some Gym environments return the `done` flag to signal episode max time steps. They should not really return that, it can send spurious signals to your agent. One way to avoid the issue is to terminate earlier, and reset the environment, at the agent.

Comment: I am not sure why do you suggest that the `done` variable affects performance. I have used it with success in many of the OpenAI envs. I even include it in my custom envs. Apart from that its usage is needed especially if you are using Generalized Advantage Estimators or n-step rewards as it indicates when an episode is done so you dont propagate the collected reward from the next sequence of actions back to the first one. @Atuos: For SGD did you try to change the learning rate?

Comment: @Constantinos: At least one gym environment - Lunar Lander, returns `done` to signal a timeout that *is not part of the problem being solved*. This is a major problem for environments which may end with a negative reward, such as LunarLander-v2, because ending the episode by timing out may be preferable to other solutions. The agent will learn to time out the episode instead of solving the problem presented. In *some* environments that might indeed be the goal, but in others it is spurious, and needs to be worked around or ignored.

Comment: @Neil `done` always indicates the end of your trials and has nothing to do with the problem being solved or not. You need only this and then use the trajectory generated so you can do PG, DQN, etc. If the agent chooses to loose (i.e ending the episode sooner) and never experiences the final reward then the agent is not suitable for that env (or you need some reward shaping). Imagine Montezuma revenge using simple DQN and getting penalty for every step. The agent of course will prefer to loose as soon as possible. But this means that the agent is not suitable and needs a more sophisticated one.

Comment: @Constantinos: It's more fundamental than that. The problem is that `done` == "terminal state". It is the only way that gym flags a terminal state. This is not to do with quality of agent, but the *definition* of the problem being solved. If the timeout was actually part of the problem to be solved (i.e. "the agent has run out of time" in an episodic problem), then the time step id should be part of the state. It isn't in gym, and problems in Open AI's gym that timeout using `done` flag are not well-formed MDPs

Comment: @Neil I am not sure that I understand where is the problem. Could you give me an example, for example in Policy Gradient methods how the `done` flag would affect your agent in a bad way? I cannot see it affecting equations. Or why it is not a well-formed MDP (i am not sure what this means though, you either have an MDP or not). I might misunderstood, its just I dont see how this affects any equation.

Comment: By the way you can have MDPs without a terminal state; `done` does not indicate reaching a terminal (goal) state in the MDP. Openai doesn't use it as indicator of that even if the MDP has a terminal state. Also the Monitor functions will not reset anymore if `done`=`False`. So if you design your own environment and you want to include goals you need to assign `done`=`True`.
Eventually `done` can mean: max steps reached or terminal state (reaching goal, or game over).

Comment: @Constantinos: I think a proper explanation would need to be a separate question and not comments on this one. In short though, there is no other way to detect terminal state in Gym as far as I know. It absolutely affects the equations, because return after terminal state is defined as 0, whilst if it were not a terminal state it is an unknown quantity (that could be e.g. bootstrapped).

Comment: @Neil The problem with what you are saying is that you do not need to define or have terminal states in a MDP in order to solve it. You can even have a problem that never terminates and the agent focuses only on maximizing average reward. Anyways as you said this is a conversation between you and me and has nothing to do with the question so I stop here :)

Comment: @Constantinos: I am aware of that. My comments are about environments that do have terminal states. Gym's CartPolve-v0 is one of them, and in general Gym does not flag terminal states vs continuing-but-timed-out-pragmatically situations differently. That is a problem that needs handling in any agent code

Comment: Neil is right. Not correctly differentiating between terminal states and timed out episodes can be problematic for episodic tasks. Whilst I don’t think this is the problem you are facing, the solution for this is to return an indicator of true termination in the info variable returned from step. This can then be handled in Generalized Advantage Estimation by appending the predicted value for the last state’s reward in timed-out episodes or appending 0 if the episode truthfully terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Stochastic gradient descent (SGD) can get stuck in saddle points which results in the model not converging. A saddle points gradient is where zero in many directions but not all directions.

Adam adaptively changes the learning rate based on past gradients. This additional information can allow the model to escape saddle points, thus the model is more likely to converge.

Answer (score 0):

- ADAM: Adaptive Moment Estimation, this optimization algorithm take both momentum and the sum squares of the gradient is considered when calculating delta for the next iteration.
- SDG: Gradient Descent in TF-Keras can be implemented with momentum modification (not by default though), this is simply the previous gradient multiply by some decay rate. If no momentum is used then it is as Brian said before. If some momentum was used then the result may just be converging slower because SDG may take a longer path to get to the minimum without accounting for the sum squares.
  For more info, this is a great article: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-visual-explanation-of-gradient-descent-methods-momentum-adagrad-rmsprop-adam-f898b102325c